# Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.CoordinatorLayout"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to use a coordinatorlayout in a fragment XML file, but I'm getting this error. I've been hitting this wall for some time now and it's starting to drive me crazy.

I've tried a number of different things, but nothing has worked. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class CoordinatorLayout ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/TnpApp.TnpApp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/TnpApp.TnpApp-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
  at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/TnpApp.TnpApp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/TnpApp.TnpApp-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
  at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:665)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:65)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
  at at md5be8727c6e6990bc4e9301ed0ea72b54c.TopicalFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
  at at md5be8727c6e6990bc4e9301ed0ea72b54c.TopicalFragment.onCreateView(TopicalFragment.java:29)
  at at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2069)
  at at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:899)
  at at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1072)
  at at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:852)
  at at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
  at at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:452)
  at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
  at Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.CoordinatorLayout
  at at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
  at at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
  at at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
  at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
  at ... 24 more
  at Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Here's my fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#aa000000"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/commentaryimage"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="#703c6a87" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/chevron_left"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:id="@+id/up_button" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Topical"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/today"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ListView
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/topicalList"
                android:divider="#309A9A9A"
                android:dividerHeight="1px" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: see this tutorial http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator, `fill_parent` is deprecate now

Comment: @DarckBlezzer `fill_parent` removed, but that doesn't impact the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` library is probably not referenced in your project.

Please reference it through Nuget, and the error should be gone:

[image]

Comment: I've done this, but it's not helping. Any other ideas?

Comment: You've done this and the error is still the same? I mean the error `Didn't find class "android.view.CoordinatorLayout"`.

Comment: Also please change `CoordinatorLayout` to `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`. Let me know if you get the same error after this is done.

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes the error has changed. Let me verify a couple things and I'll post more details.

Comment: Yep, adding the package fixes that particular error. Thanks for the answer!